# How do I make code save local variables between its processes in python like ipython notebook does?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, steam

I think my title isn't clear so... I made this code which fetches top Dota TV games as an array of these match_ids and prints them in the end. `STEAM_LGN`, `STEAM_PSW` are steam login/password combination.

```
from steam.client import SteamClient
from dota2.client import Dota2Client

client = SteamClient()
dota = Dota2Client(client)

@client.on('logged_on')
def start_dota():
    dota.launch()

match_ids = []
@dota.on('top_source_tv_games')
def response(result):
    for match in result.game_list: # games
        match_ids.append(match.match_id)  
    
def request_matches():
    dota.request_top_source_tv_games()

client.cli_login(username=STEAM_LGN, password=STEAM_PSW)

request_matches()
dota.on('top_source_tv_games', response)
print(match_ids)
```

The thing I'm having a problem with

When using Anaconda iPython Notebook -> when I run the cell for the first time -> it returns me

`[]`

but when I do it for the second time, it returns me a real data, for example

`[5769568657, 5769554974, 5769555609, 5769572298, 5769543230, 5769561446, 5769562113, 5769552763, 5769550735, 5769563870]`

So every time when I am playing in my ipython notebook sandbox -> I hit `Shift+Enter` twice and get the data.

But now I need to tranfer this code to a bigger project. So for example let's say I save that code to `dota2.info.py` file and have this code in another file referencing `dota2.info.py`:

```
import subprocess
import time 

### some code ###

while(True):
    subprocess.call(['python', './dota2info.py'])
    time.sleep(10)
```

And when running project code this always prints `[]` like it was doing on first `Shift+Enter` cell-running in Anaconda ipython notebook.

```
[]
[] 
[]
...
```

So my question is what should I do in this situation ? How can I solve this problem of (I don't know) ValvePython/dota2 code caching some important data in local unknown to me variables in ipython notebook?

Ideally I want the code immediately give me real data without having these `[]`.

Comment: It seems like an issue with the API endpoint you're hitting. If there were a bounty I would be willing to read the api docs but since you've nested API clients and are applying a bunch of method decorators it's not a simple solve for me. [Dota docs](https://demodota2api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) & [steam docs](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @will.cass.wrig these decorators aren't nested by me. This is how Valve intended to use their library https://dota2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ (btw dota2api library which you linked seems to be outdated so I haven't used it)

Comment: sorry i can't help. maybe raise it as an issue on the github repo if you don't get a response here in the next day or so [dota2 github](https://github.com/ValvePython/dota2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell why it happens, but as a possible workaround I'd try wrapping the code in the cell you're re-running, in a function that retries until nonempty results are achieved.

For example, assuming everything was in the rerun cell except the imports, this might be `dota2info.py`:

```
from steam.client import SteamClient
from dota2.client import Dota2Client
import time

def get_results():
    client = SteamClient()
    dota = Dota2Client(client)

    @client.on('logged_on')
    def start_dota():
        dota.launch()

    match_ids = []
    @dota.on('top_source_tv_games')
    def response(result):
        for match in result.game_list: # games
            match_ids.append(match.match_id)  
        
    def request_matches():
        dota.request_top_source_tv_games()

    client.cli_login(username=STEAM_LGN, password=STEAM_PSW)

    request_matches()
    dota.on('top_source_tv_games', response)
    return match_ids

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = get_results()
    max_retries = 10
    retries = 0
    while not results and retries < max_retries:
        time.sleep(3)  # wait number of seconds to retry
        results = get_results()
        retries += 1

    print(results)
```